# choosing random numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: probability

A and B choose random numbers x and y, b/w 0 and 1. consider :
a = {abs value of the difference of the two numbers is at most 1/3}
b = {none of the numbers exceeds 2/3}

find P (a), p (b), p (A intersection b).

i created the square and calculated the areas but which is the answer for which, that i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the graphs for a (first) and b (second). Can you calculate area from them and find $P(a\cap b)$?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the seocnf is incorrect, will correct it in a minute

Comment: the area for the first one 7/9 and the second one is 2/9 and the intersection is just 5/9

Comment: My opinion is : $P(a) = 5/9$ (square 1x1 minus two right triangles with catheti = 2/3), $P(b) = 4/9 : P(b) = P\{x \leq 2/3\} * P\{y \leq 2/3\}$. $P(a\cap b) = 3/9 = 1/3$ (can be simply get from the graphs, area of intersection).

Comment: thanks alot for all your help